# Access local files through Google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I need to load a list of names into my google chrome extension from a local file,
How can this be done? what if the file is shipped with the extension itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this file is shipped with your extension then you can just load it with `XMLHttpRequest` inside background page (use relative paths, with `/` being extension root folder).

You can also make your file to be javascript (`var config=[...]`) and just load it with `<script>` into background page.

Answer (score 5):

Say your json file is names.json in the following folder

```
-- manifest.json
-- config
   |-- names.json
```

In **manifest.json** add path to the resource

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
        "config/names.json"
    ]
```

Use **fectch()** API to access the resource

```
const url = chrome.runtime.getURL('./config/names.json');

fetch(url)
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }

      // Examine the text in the response
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
```