# How To Access Local File System With Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a Chrome extension but I have encountered a problem. I need access to a file that is in the same directory as my JS script. Here is the representation:

my_script.js 
 My Folder
  |-> my_file.file

I use a third party library that does some required things with it. And I need to pass in the path to my_file.file The problem is ***my_script.js*** gets injected into the website I am trying to change and the code instead of searching on the local file system it tries to find it in ***[www.website.com/My](http://www.website.com/My) Folder/my_file.file*** which obviously does not exist. How can I make it so that it seacrhes relative to my_script.js? I unfortunately can't pass the file itself to ***func()***, it has to be the path of the file. The file I am trying to reach is about 200MB which I was planning on shipping with my extension. Also this project is vanilla JS. Thank you!

### my_script.js

```
...
lib.func('My Folder/my_file.file').then(function (out) {
    document.out = out;
});
...
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621822/access-local-files-through-google-chrome-extension

Comment: Use [chrome.runtime.getURL('My Folder/my_file.file')](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getURL)

Comment: Thank you to both! I was able to solve it using getURL() and adding the file path to web_accessible_resources in the manifest.